# Recyclerview not showing in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have placed a `recyclerView` in a `fragment` but I can't seem to see where the mistake is. I've tried numerous fixes but the app keeps crashing.

Can someone help me get the `recyclerView` to display in the `fragment` please?

My code for java file

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("VIEW ALL MODULES");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    moduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Module m1 = new Module(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, "ONT4101", "DEV SOFT", "NMU", "ITC", "Haskins");
    Module m2 = new Module(2, 1, 5, 37, 44, "AIN4002", "AI", "NMU", "ITC", "THUG LIFE");
    Module m3 = new Module(3, 2, 2, 13, 44, "ONT4300", "PROJECT", "NMU", "ITC", "Haskins");
    moduleList.add(m1);
    moduleList.add(m2);
    moduleList.add(m3);
    moduleAdapter = new ModuleAdapter(getActivity(), moduleList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_all_module, container, false);
}
```

The XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ViewAllModuleFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter class

```
 public class ModuleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModuleAdapter.ModuleViewHolder>{
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Module> moduleList;
    public ModuleAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Module> moduleList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.moduleList = moduleList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ModuleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

        View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.module_list, parent, false);
        return new ModuleViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ModuleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Module module = moduleList.get(position);
        holder.textModCodeView.setText(module.getModcode());
        holder.textModuleDescView.setText(module.getModdesc());
        holder.textEducatorView.setText("Educator: "+ module.getEducator());
        holder.textNoOfTestView.setText("Tests: "+ String.valueOf(module.getNooftest()));
        holder.textNoOfAssView.setText("Assignments: "+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofass()));
        holder.textNoOfPracView.setText("Practicals: "+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofprac()));
        holder.textNoOfExamView.setText("Exams: "+ String.valueOf(module.getNoofexam()));

        Random r = new Random();
        int red=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
        int green=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
        int blue=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;

        GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
        draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        draw.setColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
        holder.textModCodeView.setBackground(draw);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moduleList.size();
    }

    class ModuleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textModCodeView,textModuleDescView,textEducatorView,textNoOfTestView,textNoOfAssView,textNoOfPracView,textNoOfExamView;
        public ModuleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textModCodeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textModCodeView);
            textModuleDescView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textModuleDescView);
            textEducatorView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textEducatorView);
            textNoOfTestView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfTestView);
            textNoOfAssView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfAssView);
            textNoOfPracView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfPracView);
            textNoOfExamView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNoOfExamView);
        }
    }
}
```

I have imported the dependencies for `RecyclerView`and `CardView`.
Please help.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and explanations, I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to inflate the layout of the fragment and then initialize the `RecyclerView`. Try this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("VIEW ALL MODULES");
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_all_module, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    moduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Module m1 = new Module(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, "ONT4101", "DEV SOFT", "NMU", "ITC", "Haskins");
    Module m2 = new Module(2, 1, 5, 37, 44, "AIN4002", "AI", "NMU", "ITC", "THUG LIFE");
    Module m3 = new Module(3, 2, 2, 13, 44, "ONT4300", "PROJECT", "NMU", "ITC", "Haskins");
    moduleList.add(m1);
    moduleList.add(m2);
    moduleList.add(m3);
    moduleAdapter = new ModuleAdapter(getActivity(), moduleList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

This line gets the recycler view from your activity. I don't think that is your intention.

`recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`

If you really defined the recycler view in the fragment, you should be inflating that layout from that fragment and find the recyclerview from there. The correct way to inflate a view in fragment and find the recyclerview is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_all_module, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line has the error and makes your app crash:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

Since the recycler view is not a part of the MainActivity so finding it in the context of the MainAcitvity will cause the crash. You will need to find it the View inflated from the XML file of the fragment, like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_all_module, container, false);
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

And then set the Adapter and Layout Managers on the Recycler View.

One suggestion: Since your fragment layout only consists of a Recycler View then you should consider using a FrameLayout as a container for that Recycler View instead of a LinearLayout although this has nothing to do with the crash but if you are planing to only adding a RecyclerView (i.e. a single item) then FrameLayout is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'    // use this inside app level gradle